# WiX: Install C++ 2005 before Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, wix, wix3.5

Using VS 2012 and WiX 3.5, I am trying to create a WiX installer that will install a program I have written which requires Crystal Reports (using "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" version 13_0_6).  I found this [link](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Using+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Merge+Modules+%28MSM%29+to+create+a+Setup+project) that explains that the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 merge modules are required for Crystal Reports to work.

I have two questions about this:

1) I am using VS 2012 and therefore have the VC110_* merge files available to me.  Is it ok to use these merge files or do I need to get the specific C++ 2005 files?

2) Can I somehow with WiX create an installer that will first install the C++ files and then do the Crystal Report files?  Right now I am getting the error referenced in the link above which means C++ is not installed on the target machine.

Here is the snippet of my WiX file showing how I am including the merge files:

```
        ...
        <Feature Id="WpfCrystalReports" Title="WPF Crystal Reports" Level="1">
          <MergeRef Id="MSVC110CRTx86" />
          <MergeRef Id="CrystalRuntime" />
          <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>

        </Feature>    
        </Product>


      <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
          <Merge Id="MSVC110CRTx86" SourceFile="Microsoft_VC110_CRT_x86.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
          <Merge Id="CrystalRuntime" SourceFile="CRRuntime_13_0_6.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0" />
          <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      ...
```